# Explode an array php

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I had a array of list like this :

```
A = (a.11, b.12, c.dd)
```

I want to store the above array values in two different arrays like

```
B = (a, b, c)
C = (11,12,dd)
```

I tried a lot but all in vain. i am bit new to php. please help me out in this regard. Your prompt response is highly appreciated
Thanx

Comment: Have you tried something till yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you:

```
$a = array("a.11,b.12,c.dd");
$b = array();
$d = array();
foreach ($a as $val)
{
    $c =explode(',', $val);
    foreach ($c as $v)
    {
        $e =explode('.', $v);
        array_push($b,$e[0]);
        array_push($d,$e[1]);
    }
}

print_r($b);
print_r($d);
```

Working [demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/149bc4926bbec569051d6706f5ebfe5d641fd421)

Comment: Yes i have tried alot..but the problem is this that the above array which i want to explaode i.e.

Comment: @user3723161 Have you tried the above code? Is that the results you were expecting?

Comment: Well thanku very much for ur prompt response..but it didnt fulfil my requirement. As i wrote before in my above comment that A is a string and store the whole value as index 0 of an array..

Comment: I've edited the code to satisfy your criteria as now `$a` is an array of single string.

Comment: thanku so mch..it worked for me..u save my day..hats off..bundle of thnx man.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($A as $v) {
    $v = explode('.', $v);
    $B[] = $v[0];
    $C[] = $v[1]
}
```

Comment: Hi, code-only answers might solve the problem, but they are way less valuable to further readers, than an answer, that also contains some explaination. Therefore it would be highly appreciated, if you could expand your answer to include some explaination.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$C = [];
$B = array_map(function($v) use(&$C){$arr = explode('.', $v); $C[] = $v[1]; return $v[0];}, $A);
```